# Trying extjs5 simple gridpanel (example doesnt work)

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

Im using [this example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/components/grids/grids.html) to learn how to use extjs5, im creating a simple gridpanel, but doesnt work for me (in the example use the `renderTo: Ext.getBody()`, i changed this part to `renderTo: 'example-grid'` to show inside the `<div id="example-grid">` but the div shows empty. Here is the code:

```
<head>
<html:base />
<title><bean:write name="UserFormBean" property="Nombre"/></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../config/ext-theme-classic/build/resources/ext-theme-classic-all.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../config/ext-theme-classic/build/resources/ext-theme-classic-all-debug.css" type="text/css" />

<script src="../../../../config/js/ExtLocale/<%=request.getSession(true).getAttribute( "langSesion")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../../config/ext-theme-classic/build/ext-theme-classic.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../../config/ext-theme-classic/build/ext-theme-classic-debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../../config/js/ext-all-5.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../../config/js/ext-all-debug-5.0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
Ext.onReady(function() {

    //MODEL
    Ext.define('User', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [ 'name', 'email', 'phone' ]
    });

    // DATASTORE
    var userStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'User',
        data: [
            { name: 'Lisa', email: 'lisa@simpsons.com', phone: '555-111-1224' },
            { name: 'Bart', email: 'bart@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1234' },
            { name: 'Homer', email: 'homer@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1244' },
            { name: 'Marge', email: 'marge@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1254' }
        ]
    });

    //GRIDPANEL
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        renderTo: 'example-grid',
        store: userStore,
        width: 400,
        height: 200,
        title: 'Application Users',
        columns: [
            {
                text: 'Name',
                width: 100,
                sortable: false,
                hideable: false,
                dataIndex: 'name'
            },
            {
                text: 'Email Address',
                width: 150,
                dataIndex: 'email',
                hidden: true
            },
            {
                text: 'Phone Number',
                flex: 1,
                dataIndex: 'phone'
            }
        ]
    });     
}    
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example-grid"></div>
```

Comment: how doesnt it work? Does it not show?

Comment: Sorry. The example-grid div shows empty

Comment: maybe you could try something like : renderTo: '#example-grid'

Comment: still does not working

Comment: Amongst other things, you've tried to include the library twice. I'd suggest you follow the getting starting guide.

Comment: Thank you Evan, i deleted the -debug.js (only i included trying "something"). now only i imported the ext-all-5.0.js and still not working.

Comment: You missed a closing parenthesis. Seems like your code has no other issues. see [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gilsha/7y5bdL42/3/)

Comment: Hi Gilsha, what clossing parenthesis is missed? (i can't see it). in other way, JsFiddle not support ExtJS5, only until 4.2. Thank you

Comment: Found, the Ext.onready close parenthesis, now it works perfectly. Can you post like answer to close and give you reputation? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code should work provided that you include necessary Ext files if you really need to use `onReady` approach (not recommended).

You can find a workable single-file approach here: [Single File ExtJS 5 Application w/o Sencha Cmd](http://extjs.eu/single-file-extjs-5-application/). It is slightly different in that that it uses `Ext.application()` instead of `onReady()`. One way or another, both are not recommended.

The recommended approach is to use `Sencha Cmd` to initially generate, maintain during development and finally build the Ext application.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have it done in my project :

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {..})

var pageDivs = Ext.select('div .example-grid');

//get the .Page DIV should just be one.
var pageDiv = pageDivs.elements[0];

grid.render(pageDiv);
```

ie. use **render** instead of **renderTo**.

Comment: Thank you. I deleted the `renderTo` from `Ext.grid.Panel` and added your code but still not working. The example-grid is empty. I checked if the urls from the *.js files and are OK.

Comment: No, i tried with  `var pageDivs = Ext.select('div #example-grid');` too.

Comment: what about div#example-grid

Comment: or just Ext.select('#example-grid')

Comment: Gilsha founded the problem, only a closing parenthesis at final. (closing the Ext.onReady). Thank you for your help.